# Managing memory usage with infinite lists

Tags: haskell

So I am trying to find ways to make the number 5 using the number 15

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Omega
import System.IO

data Expr = X | Sub Expr Expr | Div Expr Expr | Pow Expr Expr
          deriving Show

eval x X = x
eval x (Sub a b) = eval x a -  eval x b
eval x (Div a b) = eval x a /  eval x b
eval x (Pow a b) = eval x a ** eval x b

exprs | v <- each exprs
      = (X:) . concat $ transpose
      [ runOmega $ liftM2 Div v v
      , runOmega $ liftM2 Sub v v
      , runOmega $ liftM2 Pow v v
      ]

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering
  mapM_ print $ filter ((==5).eval 15) exprs
```

However, the first result is the 118588079th element in the list, and Haskell runs out of memory long before getting there. How do I know the first one is 118588079? Because if I just calculate it and ask for the index instead, Haskell uses no memory at all:

```
run x | v <- each $ run x
      = (x:) . concat $ transpose
      [ runOmega $ liftM2 (/ ) v v
      , runOmega $ liftM2 (- ) v v
      , runOmega $ liftM2 (**) v v
      ]

main = print . map snd . filter ((==5).fst) $ zip (run 15) [0..]
```

Where exactly is my memory going in the first case, and how do I get around it?

Comment: This is a wild guess but laziness might be at work here?

Comment: I suggest that you post your edits as an answer.

Comment: @duplode I agree, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A top level binding like

```
list = [1..1000000]
```

will lazily produce the list once, and keep it in memory for subsequent use.

A function, instead,

```
fun x = [1..1000000]
```

will allocate a new list at every call, recomputing it (lazily) from scratch every time. Because it's referred by a top level binding, it will never be garbage collected.

Note that this is not mandated by Haskell -- it's just GHC which works in this way.

For comparison, try this variant:

```
run x | v <- each $ run x
      = (x:) . concat $ transpose
      [ runOmega $ liftM2 (/ ) v v
      , runOmega $ liftM2 (- ) v v
      , runOmega $ liftM2 (**) v v
      ]
run15 = run 15
main = print . map snd . filter ((==5).fst) $ zip run15 [0..]
```

You should see a lot of memory being consumed, since no garbage collection can happen. Instead,

```
main = print . map snd . filter ((==5).fst) $ zip run15 [0..]
   where 
   run15 = run 15
```

should allow for garbage collection and run in a small amount of memory.

(By the way, that use of a pattern binding instead of let/where puzzled me for a while.)

Comment: @BlackCap Wow... I wasn't expecting that. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

@chi is exactly right. A function with no arguments is not really a function, and will be kept in memory, regardless of how recursive it is,  whether it produces an infinite datastructure or not. This will cause you to run out of memory:

```
run' | v <- each run'
     = (15:) . concat $ transpose
     [ runOmega $ liftM2 (/ ) v v
     , runOmega $ liftM2 (- ) v v
     , runOmega $ liftM2 (**) v v
     ]

main = print $ run' !! 1000000000
```

while the first `run` function will not. On the same note- despite looking silly- this will not run out of memory:

```
exprs' x | v <- each $ exprs' x
         = (x:) . concat $ transpose
         [ runOmega $ liftM2 Div v v
         , runOmega $ liftM2 Sub v v
         , runOmega $ liftM2 Pow v v
         ]

main = print $ exprs' X !! 1000000000
```

### PS

If anyone is curious, the 118588079th element in the list was `((((x**x)/x)-(x**(x-(x/x))))-((x-x)-(x/x)))`